# linux if script exists in mnt execute script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a script that checks /mnt/sda b c d... for the existence of a shell script. When it finds the script, it needs to execute it.
Here's what I have so far:

```
for x in a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2 d1 d2 e1 e2 f1 f2; do /mnt/sd$x/1_drive_check.sh; done
```

This is OK, but it actually tries to run the script in each mount point.  Normally I wouldn't care, but I need to have a minimal amount of information showing up in the console.

I know about the command to check if a file exists.

```
if [ -f 1_drive_check.sh ] then
echo 1_drive_check.sh exists!
fi
```

What I don't know how to do is merge the two together to see if 1_drive_check.sh exists in /sda1 or sda2 or sdb1, etc. then execute it.  I tired a hot glue gun but I burnt myself.

FYI, I'm REALLY new at this since I'm used to working with VBS on a regular basis.

Comment: `for ...; do if [ ... ]; then /mnt/sd$x/1_drive_check.sh; fi;done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the `for ...; do if [ ... ]; then /mnt/sd$x/1_drive_check.sh; fi;done` solution, you could:

```
find /mnt/ -maxdepth 2 -name '1_drive_check.sh' -executable -exec {} \;
```

... saves adding drives manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought...

```
for script in /mnt/sd[a-f]{1,2}/1_drive_check.sh
do
    $script
done
```

Only finds the scripts that are actually there.